# Changing ulimit on ubuntu 12.04 Never works

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, ulimit

I am working with hadoop and need to change number of open files `ulimit -n`. I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere and have tried everything in those answers, but it still does not work. I am working with `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`. Here is what i have done:

change limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, i have put in settings for * and `root`. I have also changed  limits to some number like `10000` and `unlimited`.

```
* soft nofile 1513687
* hard nofile 1513687
root soft nofile 1513687
root hard nofile 1513687
```

I have also tried above setting with `-` instead of `soft` and `hard`. After these changes, i have made changes to `/etc/pam.d/` files such as:

```
common-session 
common-session-noninterative
login
cron
sshd
su
sudo
```

i have added `session required pam_limits.so` to the beginning of each file. I made a restart of the box in question and the settings did not take effect.

I have also found that there were files inside `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory for the users `hbase` `mapred` and `hdfs`. I have tried changing limits in these individual files as well to no avail.

I have tried putting `ulimit -S -n unlimited` inside `/etc/profile` as well. It did not work.

Finally, i have tried putting `limit nofile unlimited unlimited` inside `/etc/init.d/hadoop*` files as first line. Did not work.

One interesting thing though is, i do not have hbase installed on the box but i do have a `hbase.conf` file inside `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory. The settings in this file are reflected with `ulimit -n`. But settings from `hdfs.conf` and `mapred.conf` are not reflected. Which suggests that something is overwriting settings for `hdfs` and `mapred`.

I guess i have tried everything people suggested on several forums, is there anything else that i may have missed or done incorrectly?

I am using `CDH 4.4.0` as my hadoop distribution.

Comment: Well, why do we have a close vote here? isn't this a valid question? I have done my research and things are still not working. I am surprised that people vote  for close for such detailed question.

Comment: It is not for SO. It is more for askubuntu ([as you found out](http://askubuntu.com/questions/396429/changing-ulimit-on-ubuntu-12-04-never-works)) or superuser. No programming in here...

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking ulimit?

I was experiencing a similar issue, where I would run `sudo ulimit -n`, and still see `1024`. This is because `ulimit` is a Bash built-in. In order to see the changes reflected in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, I had to run `ulimit` as the actual user.

Comment: yeah i have tried that as well. used hdfs user to check ulimit. doesn't work for me somehow.